# Cyclic type of the product of two permutations

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Maybe this question is way too simple but I'm stuck. Suppose $x,y \in S_n$ and the product $xy$ has the cyclic type $(t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n)$; here $t_i$ is the number of cycles of length $i$ when we present $xy$ as a product of independent cycles.

> What can we say about the cyclic type of $yx$?

Any hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$yx$ has the same cyclic type as $xy$ as the two are conjugate: $yx=x^{-1}\cdot xy\cdot x$.

Comment: Ha! Thanks, now I'm ashamed :)